# Is there a way to plot a function which is a partial derivate of a function with 2 variables in python?

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I am using sympy to get the partial derivative of a function with two variables. This is what I have been trying but I am getting an error of using the same variable.

```
from sympy.plotting import *
import numpy as np
x=symbols('x')
y=symbols('y')
diff((cos(x))*cos(y)*(exp((-x)**2))*(exp((-y)**2)), x)
f=diff((cos(x))*cos(y)*(exp((-x)**2))*(exp((-y)**2)), x)
p1=plot(f,show=False)
p1
p1.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with sympy but it seems cool and this looked like a good starting point. From what I can tell you some extraneous code. Here is how I refactored it (using import * out of sheer laziness and not knowing what else you might want to do):

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
f=diff((cos(x))*cos(y)*(exp((-x)**2))*(exp((-y)**2)), x)
derivative_f = f.diff(x)
derivative_f
```

Which gives you a very pretty:

4222 cos()cos() − 422 sin()cos()+22 cos()cos()

Comment: Now that I got the derivate_f, can you tell me how can I plot this on a 3d graph using plot or any python libraries?

Comment: Not against taking another shot at it but you should ask it as a separate question so it becomes part of the knowledge base others can access.